# ShapeRenderer doesn't render when using Skins

Tags: libgdx

My shapes drawn by shape renderer does not show when I use skins. The shape is drawn inside the actor using an instance of ShapeRenderer. I think this is caused by the skin because I tried adding an empty table and the shapes show, but if I add an instance of a skin the shapes does not show.

This code is from the libgdx tests in github:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

Label nameLabel = new Label("Name:", skin);

Table t1 = new Table();
t1.setFillParent(true);
t1.add(nameLabel);
stage.addActor(t1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `.end()` the `SpriteBatch` befor using the `ShapeRender.begin()` after the `ShapeRender.end()` you need to call `SpriteBatch.begin()` in your actor. Else you do have 2 concurenting batches.

```
actor.draw(SpriteBatch batch, float delta){
   batch.end();
   ShapeRender.begin(Some Typee);//start it with your shapetype
   //drawing stuff with the shaperender
   ShapeRender.end();//dont forget to end it
   batch.begin(); //need to be started again for the next actors to be dawn
}
```

An empty table shouldnt be a problem.